# How to avoid a div overlapping another fixed div in Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
    <html>
<head>
    <link href="hue.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">

        <div class="column">
            <div class="form">
                <div class="form-nivel">
                    <label for="cfdiCreate:organizationRfc">RFC</label><label id="cfdiCreate:organizationRfc">XXXXXXXXXXXX</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-nivel">
                    <label for="cfdiCreate:organizationTaxSystem">Regimen    fiscal</label><label id="cfdiCreate:organizationTaxSystem">Sueldos y salarios</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-nivel">
                    <label for="cfdiCreate:organizationTaxAddress">Domicilio  fiscal</label><label id="cfdiCreate:organizationTaxAddress">XXXXXX Colonia Tecnológico  Monterrey,Nuevo León,México.C.P.XXXXXX</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-nivel">
                    <label for="cfdiCreate:organizationExpeditionPlace">Lugar de  expedición</label><label id="cfdiCreate:organizationExpeditionPlace">Suc.1 Chiapas,México.     </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column secondary">
            <!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

`position :fixed` makes the `div` fixed but it is overlapped by other `div` when we scroll down. How do I make this row fixed at top and not let this `div` get overlapped by another `div` whenever we scroll down.

Comment: Google CSS `z-index`.

Comment: Without seeing your CSS this is hard to answer, but z-index would be a good place to start.

Comment: Can you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)... it will be difficult to offer answers to your problem without seeing how you have set up your CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I was to guess what you wanted (a fixed top bar that stays on top of the content/divs under it all the way down the page), something like this:

```
.column {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}

.secondary {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

Check out this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/JRKyte/pen/DGbin) with an example, I've shortened down your code to only the necessary bits.

Comment: By doing this column gets over .secondary but they still overlapping remains?How can we prevent this and put one div below another.

Comment: By keeping margin top at second div we can remove the overlapping but isn't  there any method which keeps the other div just below  the fixed div without overlapping the other div something like float which does not works in case of fixed div?@Jon Kyte

Comment: @known Setting an elements position to `fixed` takes it out of the document flow, and so other elements cannot stack against it unfortunately.